# disbale user in usermanager mikroitk

Tags: script, mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

I have Mikrotik version 6 and my users are connected to usermanager and use internet. I want to disable all users in usermanager for one hour and then activate it with another script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Indeed please do [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1768566/edit) your question. More details are needed to provide an answer. Just for example - usermanager is a RADIUS-based authentication server; do you want just to prevent authentication for one hour, or do you want to also drop the internet connection from all users at the same go? From where and how do you connect to the device / authenticator? And so on... The more details, the better answers. Please have a look at [how to write a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice. Please don't respond in a  comment.